# How can I wait for a page loader, which appears and disappears based on API call, to disappear before performing action on element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

As the title states, I am trying to perform an action (i.e., sendkeys or click etc.) on an element but the loader (which has ID) is making the action inconsistent.

I have tried quite a few different methods, now I am onto a gimmicky method of sorts with using thread sleep which works semi-consistently, but still gets false-positives to move forward once in a while which results in test failure.

The loader (id="spinner") disappears from the page after an API call completes (sending a signal to script that it is good to go forward), but upon the start of the next call, the loader comes back, and then disappears upon completion for (currently) 3 API calls.  I would like to devise a way for this to work regardless of how many calls are implemented.

```
public void Loader()
{    
   WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,50);
   WebElement CPloader = driver.findElement(By.id("spinner"));
   boolean test = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("spinner")));         

   if(test==false) {
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("spinner")));
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(CPloader));
       threadsleep(2000);
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("spinner")));
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(CPloader));
       threadsleep(2000);
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("spinner")));
       wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(CPloader));
   }

}
```

In the test script code, I am usually putting loader method, threadsleep, loader method in an attempt to get it to hold off for long enough but I know this isn't proper... example below:

```
Util.Loader();
Util.threadsleep(2000);
Util.Loader();
//click element or send keys etc
```

I am imagining this to be a loop of sorts with an invisibility wait but can't seem to figure it out.

Any pointers in the right direction would be of great help.

Comment: If a human were interacting with this page, how would they know when it is safe to proceed?

Comment: They wouldn't be trying to hit all the inputs while the page had a huge loader and overlay in progress.  More often than not the loader/overlay is quick, but sometimes it gets hung on a call for a few seconds or something, which is where I think the threadsleep and recheck for invisibility helps, but I'm still getting some false-positives.

Comment: In response to DebanjanB's answer, I also should note I have `elementToBeClickable()`, AND `visibilityOfElementLocated` in all of the buttons/send key targeted fields. This still gets tricked out by the moment that the loader disappears and then reappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by waiting for the loader to appear then disappear... and do this in a loop. Once the loader stops appearing, the wait will throw a `TimeoutException`. Catch that with a `try-catch` and break out of the loop. You may need to tweak the 10s wait up or down depending on how much time generally passes between loading spinners.

```
public static void Loader()
{
    By loader = By.id("spinner");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(loader));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(loader));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally have time to get back to this.  This definitely adds a level of consistency so thanks for the help.  One thing to note is this increases run time significantly which I guess that's just a trade-off I'll have to live with. Much better to take a bit longer than to fail 1 out of 5 times.  Thanks again.

Comment: It shouldn't increase run time at all. It only waits until the condition is true, not the full wait time. That's the benefit of `WebDriverWait` vs a `Thread.Sleep()`.

Answer (score 0):

AS you mentioned the *loader (which has ID) is making the action inconsistently* so instead of invoking `invisibilityOfElementLocated()` method for the loader you can invoke [**`elementToBeClickable()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method for the desired element for which you intent to invoke `click()` or `sendKeys()` as follows :

- Using *cssSelector* and *click* :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("cssSelector_of_element_to_interact"))).click();
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *sendKeys* :

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("xpath_of_element_to_interact']"))).sendKeys("Test");
  ```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have `elementToBeClickable()`, AND `visibilityOfElementLocated` in all of the buttons/send key targeted fields.  This still gets tricked out by the moment that the loader disappears and then reappears.